# SQL Query Problem

Tags: mysql, left-join, expressionengine

I've been at this for a bit now. Basically, I'm needing to add a derived column to count the hits to a weblog entry in the database. The problem is, the hits are being totaled and shown on only on the first record. Any Ideas? I've emboldened the parts of the query I'm talking about. The query is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t.entry_id), 
    exp_categories.rank, 
    **exp_hits.hits,** 
    t.entry_id, 
    t.weblog_id, 
    t.forum_topic_id, 
    t.author_id, 
    t.ip_address, 
    t.title, 
    t.url_title, 
    t.status, 
    t.dst_enabled, 
    t.view_count_one, 
    t.view_count_two, 
    t.view_count_three, 
    t.view_count_four, 
    t.allow_comments, 
    t.comment_expiration_date, 
    t.allow_trackbacks, 
    t.sticky, 
    t.entry_date, 
    t.year, 
    t.month, 
    t.day, 
    t.entry_date, 
    t.edit_date, 
    t.expiration_date, 
    t.recent_comment_date, 
    t.comment_total, 
    t.trackback_total, 
    t.sent_trackbacks, 
    t.recent_trackback_date, 
    t.site_id as entry_site_id, 
    w.blog_title, 
    w.blog_name, 
    w.search_results_url, 
    w.search_excerpt, 
    w.blog_url, 
    w.comment_url, 
    w.tb_return_url, 
    w.comment_moderate, 
    w.weblog_html_formatting, 
    w.weblog_allow_img_urls, 
    w.weblog_auto_link_urls, 
    w.enable_trackbacks, 
    w.trackback_use_url_title, 
    w.trackback_field, 
    w.trackback_use_captcha, 
    w.trackback_system_enabled, 
    m.username, 
    m.email, 
    m.url, 
    m.screen_name, 
    m.location, 
    m.occupation, 
    m.interests, 
    m.aol_im, 
    m.yahoo_im, 
    m.msn_im, 
    m.icq, 
    m.signature, 
    m.sig_img_filename, 
    m.sig_img_width, 
    m.sig_img_height, 
    m.avatar_filename, 
    m.avatar_width, 
    m.avatar_height, 
    m.photo_filename, 
    m.photo_width, 
    m.photo_height, 
    m.group_id, 
    m.member_id, 
    m.bday_d, 
    m.bday_m, 
    m.bday_y, 
    m.bio, 
    md.*, 
    wd.* 
FROM exp_weblog_titles AS t 
    LEFT JOIN exp_weblogs AS w ON t.weblog_id = w.weblog_id 
    LEFT JOIN exp_weblog_data AS wd ON t.entry_id = wd.entry_id 
    LEFT JOIN exp_members AS m ON m.member_id = t.author_id 
    LEFT JOIN exp_member_data AS md ON md.member_id = m.member_id 
    LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts ON wd.entry_id = exp_category_posts.entry_id 
    **LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS hits, exp_hits.entry_id FROM exp_hits ORDER BY exp_hits.entry_id
    ) exp_hits ON t.entry_id = exp_hits.entry_id**
    LEFT JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT exp_categories.cat_id, cat_name as rank 
        FROM exp_categories 
        WHERE exp_categories.group_id = '9' 
    ) exp_categories ON exp_categories.cat_id = exp_category_posts.cat_id 
WHERE t.entry_id IN (2,3,4) ORDER BY exp_categories.rank DESC, **exp_hits.hits DESC**, entry_date desc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changeing the subselect to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS hits, 
    exp_hits.entry_id 
FROM exp_hits 
GROUP BY exp_hits.entry_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, is your hits functionality something that can't be accomplished with the view_count_one/two/three/four fields already present in the database and supported by ExpressionEngine template tags?

Comment: Yes, because the view count functionality has to be implemented in a {weblog entries} tag. It wouldn't work for URL accessed entries.